# How can I create a WPF TextBox that conditionally converts user input?

Tags: wpf, textbox, imultivalueconverter

I want to create a TextBox that can take measurement and convert it to different units if necessary (the end result being of type `double`). The conversion will be controlled by a value `IsMetric`. If `IsMetric == true` then `"36.5 in"` would turn into `927.1` (a double representing millimeters). Conversely, if `IsMetric == false` then `"927.1 mm"` would turn into `36.5`.

I thought to use an `IValueConverter` on a regular `TextBox`, but the `ConverterParameter` is not a `DependencyProperty` and therefore I can't bind `IsMetric` to it.

I tried `IMultiValueConverter` but the `ConvertBack` function only receives the current value of the `TextBox` and not all the bound values. This means I don't know `IsMetric` when converting the user input.

Have I missed something with the `ConvertBack` function? If not, then do I need to create a class derived from `TextBox`?

Comment: Create a **Custom Control**. This will be a much more elegant solution than using a Converter. Also, when you're done, post it so I can use it :-)

Comment: Pay attention - i have already answered it (:

Answer (score 3):

You could use two converters one to convert from Metric and another to Metric:

```
public class ToMetricConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "(metric) value";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class FromMetricConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "(Inch) value";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use a `DataTrigger` in the UI to select the appropriate converter based on that bool value:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication13:ToMetricConverter x:Key="ToMetricConverter"/>
    <wpfApplication13:FromMetricConverter x:Key="FromMetricConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>    
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsMetric,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>
        <TextBox >
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">                        
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMetric,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Val,Converter={StaticResource ToMetricConverter}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMetric,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Val,Converter={StaticResource FromMetricConverter}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of the solution I came up with except I used a single Converter. I would still like to find an elegant solution for a case where IsMetric could be more than just True or False, but this certainly is an option.

Comment: Year, I do agree this is kinda ugly :p

Answer (score 0):

If thats the only thing you want to do, try other way to use converter parameter.
But, and i would have choose this option - if your textbox has more logics in it, or tend to have more dependecie - Create custom control that inherits from textbox, and add your own dependecy properties. Then you can use your IsMetric and convert it as you want on propertychanged etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something along these lines for now. Would still enjoy a solution that doesn't require a DataTrigger for every possible value.

It's a bit different than the answer posted by @SamTheDev but along the same lines.

xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.Controls.MeasurementTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Converters"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Behaviors"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="root">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <c:MeasurementUnitConverter x:Key="muc"/>
        <c:MeasurementConverter2 x:Key="mc"/>
        <sys:Boolean x:Key="BooleanFalse">False</sys:Boolean>
        <sys:Boolean x:Key="BooleanTrue">True</sys:Boolean>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 b:AutoSelectBehavior.AutoSelect="True">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseMetric, ElementName=root}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Measurement, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource mc}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource BooleanTrue}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseMetric, ElementName=root}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Measurement, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource mc}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource BooleanFalse}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <!-- in or mm label -->
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1"
                Content="{Binding UseMetric, ElementName=root, Converter={StaticResource muc}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyNamespace.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MeasurementTextBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MeasurementTextBox : UserControl
    {
        public MeasurementTextBox()
        {
            // This call is required by the designer.
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool UseMetric {
            get { return Convert.ToBoolean(GetValue(UseMetricProperty)); }
            set { SetValue(UseMetricProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseMetricProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UseMetric", typeof(bool), typeof(MeasurementTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(MeasurementTextBox.UseMetricChanged));
        private static void UseMetricChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public double Measurement {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MeasurementProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MeasurementProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty MeasurementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Measurement", typeof(double), typeof(MeasurementTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(MeasurementTextBox.MeasurementPropertyChanged));
        private static void MeasurementPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Converter

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyNamespace.Converters
{
    class MeasurementConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        const double MILLIMETERS_IN_ONE_INCH = 25.4;
        const string INCHES_ABBREVIATION = "in";
        const string MILLIMETERS_ABBREVIATION = "mm";

        const double ONE_THIRTY_SECOND = 0.03125;
        const double ONE_SIXTEENTH = 0.0625;
        const double ONE_EIGHTH = 0.125;
        const double ONE_FOURTH = 0.25;
        const double ONE_HALF = 0.5;

        const double ONE = 1;
        public double RoundToNearest(double value, int unitPrecision)
        {
            double fraction = 0;
            int reciprocal = 0;

            switch (unitPrecision)
            {
                case 0:
                    fraction = ONE;
                    reciprocal = (int)ONE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fraction = ONE;
                    reciprocal = (int)ONE;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fraction = ONE_HALF;
                    reciprocal = (int)(1 / ONE_HALF);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fraction = ONE_FOURTH;
                    reciprocal = (int)(1 / ONE_FOURTH);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fraction = ONE_EIGHTH;
                    reciprocal = (int)(1 / ONE_EIGHTH);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fraction = ONE_SIXTEENTH;
                    reciprocal = (int)(1 / ONE_SIXTEENTH);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    fraction = ONE_THIRTY_SECOND;
                    reciprocal = (int)(1 / ONE_THIRTY_SECOND);
                    break;
            }

            return Math.Round(value * reciprocal, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * fraction;

        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string strValue = (string)value;
            bool isMetric = (bool)parameter;

            double enteredValue = 0;
            bool enteredValueIsImperial = false;

            if (strValue.EndsWith(INCHES_ABBREVIATION))
            {
                enteredValueIsImperial = true;
                strValue = strValue.Substring(0, strValue.Length - INCHES_ABBREVIATION.Length);
            }
            else if (strValue.EndsWith(MILLIMETERS_ABBREVIATION))
            {
                enteredValueIsImperial = false;
                strValue = strValue.Substring(0, strValue.Length - MILLIMETERS_ABBREVIATION.Length);
            }
            else if (isMetric)
            {
                enteredValueIsImperial = false;
            }
            else
            {
                enteredValueIsImperial = true;
            }

            try
            {
                enteredValue = double.Parse(strValue);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            if (isMetric)
            {
                if (enteredValueIsImperial)
                {
                    //inches to mm
                    return RoundToNearest(enteredValue * MILLIMETERS_IN_ONE_INCH, 0);
                    //0 is mm
                }
                else
                {
                    //mm to mm
                    return RoundToNearest(enteredValue, 0);
                    //0 is mm
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (enteredValueIsImperial)
                {
                    //inches to inches
                    return RoundToNearest(enteredValue, 5);
                }
                else
                {
                    //mm to inches
                    return RoundToNearest(enteredValue / MILLIMETERS_IN_ONE_INCH, 5);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<mynamespace:MeasurementTextBox Measurement="{Binding SomeLength, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                UseMetric="{Binding IsMetric}"/>
```